# SQL INSERT with SELECT inside, maybe inner joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO gamecodes (gamecode, accountname, premium_points, alreadyused)
VALUES ('$gamecode','$accountorname',$premiumpoints,'N')
```

I need a help. In variable **$accountorname** I got a PLAYER name, i need to get his account.

Two tables:

```
TABLE PLAYERS
id, name, account_id..
id, player name, table accounts.id

TABLE ACCOUNTS
id, name ..
id = table players account_id
```

Comment: This is an `INSERT` statement. To "get his account" you will need to use a `SELECT` statement. Have you tried one yet? If so, will you post it here?

Comment: what's so hard about this? a simple select statement will give you exactly what you need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something along the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO gamecodes (gamecode, accountname, premium_points, alreadyused) 
SELECT '$gamecode',accounts.name,$premiumpoints,'N' 
FROM accounts 
JOIN players
ON accounts.id = players.account_id 
WHERE players.name = '$accountorname'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query could look something like -

```
INSERT INTO gamecodes( gamecode, accountname, premium_points, alreadyused) 
 VALUES('$gamecode', '$accountname', $premiumpoints, 'N')
 WHERE(SELECT accountname FROM accounts JOIN gamecodes ON accounts.accountname = gamecodes.accountname WHERE accounts.accountname = $accountname)
```